# Is there a toolchain to the Pico 20240 available for Ada?

Tags: pi-pico, cross-compilation, ada

For nostalgia's sake I was just unearthing some of my Ada texts from the 80's when I came upon this site [Ada on the Raspberry Pi Pico](https://pico-doc.synack.me/). GNAT Ada is available easy enough for RaspberryOS though having a 8G Rpi4 I suspect helps, and I've built the Alire package manager with little problem.

The project setup

```
alr init --bin hello_pico
cd hello_pico
alr with pico_bsp
```

works fine, and I changed the gpr file as instructed to

```
with "config/hello_pico_config.gpr";
with "pico_bsp.gpr";
project Hello_Pico is
    for Target use "arm-eabi";
    for Runtime ("Ada") use "light-cortex-m0p";
    package Linker is
        for Switches ("Ada") use Pico_BSP.Linker_Switches;
    end Linker;

    for Source_Dirs use ("src/", "config/");
```

However, the build command alr build --development fails

> pico_bsp.gpr:20:26: warning: libraries are not supported on this
> platform hal.gpr:5:24: warning: libraries are not supported on this
> platform rp2040_hal.gpr:18:25: warning: libraries are not supported on
> this platform cortex_m0.gpr:17:25: warning: libraries are not
> supported on this platform cortex_m0.gpr:4:09: no compiler for
> language "Ada", cannot compile "cortex_m-nvic.ads" gprbuild: ***
> compilation phase failed ERROR: Command ["gprbuild", "-s", "-j0",
> "-p", "-P", "/home/pi/Ada/pico/hello_pico/hello_pico.gpr"] exited with
> code 4 ERROR: Compilation failed.

The same sequence works as it should on MacOS. So it would appear the necessary toolchain to cross-compile from RaspberryOS to Pico 2040 is missing. Does any one know if one exists. I've looked in the online catalogue of software to no success.